# Virtual Box Guest Additions not working as expected

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine, linux-mint, guest-additions

I created a Ubuntu 14.04.5 virtual machine in Virtual Box 5.0.2, and my host machine is under LMDE 2.

Since a few weeks ago, everytime I create a new VM the guest additions won't work properly anymore: the Desktop is not resized when I widen the window, and sometimes the cursor won't even move until the corners of the window (I can't even select a different resolution in attached [screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AOwXR.png)).

Edit: actually it worked fine with Ubuntu 14.04.4 and 14.04.3. I noticed the Guest Additions run gives a warning: "The headers for the current running kernel were not found." ([screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/whpfI.png)). Looking for some missing dependency in 14.04.5.

Comment: Just to be clear: you are installing guest additions on every new guest VM you create, right?

Comment: Yes, so I can resize the screen (normally) and use bidirectional copy/pastes, mainly